# Reverse for 'plan_edit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['palan/edit$']

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am getting the following error:

> Reverse for 'plan_edit' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['palan/edit$']`.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^palan/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.palan_detail, name='palan_detail'),
    url(r'^palan/new/$', views.plani_new, name='plani_new'),
    url(r'^nn1/new/$', views.plani_new1, name='plani_new1'),
    url(r'^palan/edit$', views.edit, name='plan_edit'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Planning, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostFormP(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('palan_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        return render(request, 'pages/plan_edit.html')

def palan_detail(request, pk):
    palan = get_object_or_404(Planning, pk=pk) 
    j = Jour.objects.all().count() 
    return render(request, 'pages/palan_detail.html', {'palan': palan, 'j':j},)
```

**palan_detail.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'plan_edit' pk=post.pk %}">
    <h1>{{ palan.parcours }}</h1> 
</a>
<p>{{ palan.semestre|linebreaksbr }}</p>
<p>{{ palan.jour.jour1}}</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a context variable named `post` in your view. Change the following line

```
<a href="{% url 'plan_edit' pk=post.pk %}">
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'plan_edit' pk=palan.pk %}">
```