# Reverse for 'all_clients' with keyword arguments '{'client_id': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['clients/all_clients/$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I am new to Django and I am having trouble implementing the edit template to my project. I am encountering the following error:

> Reverse for 'all_clients' with keyword arguments '{'client_id': 3}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['clients/all_clients/$']

I have looked on the site for similar occurrences such as [Reverse for 'plan_edit' with keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574940/reverse-for-plan-edit-with-keyword-arguments-pk-not-found-1-pattern)

but I haven't been able to pin point the issue. I believe the issue arises when I add a hyperlink to my **all_clients.html** template. Also, the template pages for **/clients/edit_client/?/** will load, however after submission using the save changes button the NoReserse Match error resurfaces as it attempts to load the **clients/all_clients** page.

See code below:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here. 
class Client(models.Model):
    #A client is composed of the company general info
    text = models.CharField('Company Name',default = 'Company Name', max_length = 200)
    phone_num = models.CharField('Phone Number', default = '000-000-000', max_length = 12)
    ceo_name = models.CharField ('CEO', max_length = 50)
    num_employees = models.IntegerField('Number of Employees', default = 0)
    maintenance_schedule = models.CharField('maintenance schedule', max_length = 100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

**urls.py**

```
"""Defines URL patterns for clients."""

from django.urls import path from django.conf.urls import url

from .import views

app_name = 'clients' urlpatterns = [
    #Company Page
    path('index/', views.index, name = 'index'),
    
    #Page for listing all clients
    path('all_clients/', views.all_clients, name = 'all_clients'),

    #Page for adding a new client
    path('all_clients/<int:client_id>/', views.add_client, name = 'add_client'),

    #Page for adding a new client office using a form
    path('new_office/', views.new_office, name = 'new_office'),

    #Page for a company to edit their entry.
    path('edit_clients/<int:client_id>/', views.edit_client, name = 'edit_client'),
    ]
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Client, Location, Lease, Soft_Service, Hard_Service, Safety_Service
from .forms import ClientForm

# Create your views here.
def add_client(request, client_id):
    """Comapany page for updating facilities info"""
    client = Client.objects.get(id = client_id)
    context = {'client':client}
    return render(request, 'clients/add_client.html', context)

def all_clients(request):
    '''Shows list of all clients'''
    all_clients = Client.objects.order_by ('date_added')
    context = {'all_clients':all_clients}
    return render(request, 'clients/all_clients.html', context)

def index(request):
    """Test Page"""
    return render(request, 'clients/index.html')

def edit_client(request, client_id):
    """Edit an existing Entry."""
    client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #Inital request; pre-fill form with the current company info.
        form = ClientForm(instance=client)
    else:
        # Post data submitted; process data.
        form = ClientForm(instance=client, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('clients:all_clients' , client_id=client.id)

    context = {'form': form, 'client': client}
    return render(request, 'clients/edit_client.html', context)
```

**edit_client.html**

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %} {% load staticfiles %} <p><a href="{% url 'clients:add_client' client.id %}">Company: {{ client }}</a></p>

<h4>See Our Clients</h4>

<<form action="{% url 'clients:edit_client<client_id>' client.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Save changes</button> </form>
    

{% endblock %}
```

**all_clients.html**

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<div class="d-flex" style="height:75px"></div>
    <div class="btn bg-white text-lg-left" style="width:425px">
        <h4>See Our Clients</h4>

        <ul>
            {% for add_client in all_clients %}
                <li>
                    <a href=" {%  url 'clients:add_client' add_client.id %}">{{ add_client }}</a>
                </li>
            {%empty %}
                <li> No clients have been added yet. </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href=" {% url 'clients:new_office' %}">Add a new location</a>
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href=" {% url 'clients:edit_client' client.id %}">Add a new location</a>

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

First thing i think you should try is modifying the URL to the add_clients page, aside from the id you are passing is identical to all_clients, and "django may get confused":

```
#Page for listing all clients
    path('all_clients/', views.all_clients, name = 'all_clients'),

    #Page for adding a new client
    path('add_clients/<int:client_id>/', views.add_client, name = 'add_client'),
```

instead of:

```
#Page for listing all clients
    path('all_clients/', views.all_clients, name = 'all_clients'),

    #Page for adding a new client
    path('all_clients/<int:client_id>/', views.add_client, name = 'add_client'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I made that change and while the modification to **add_clients.html** works fine, the issue still persists for **all_clients.html**.

Comment: Check in all your templates in which one you have a link to 'all_clients' followed by an argument (client_id). in your URL you don't include that, that is why Django cannot find the URL

Comment: So it looks like the issue is related to two hyperlinks referencing each individual client in the all_clients.html template:

`<a href=" {%  url 'clients:add_client' add_client.id %}">{{ add_client }}</a>`

and 

`<a class="btn btn-secondary" href=" {% url 'clients:edit_client' client.id %}">Add a new location</a>`

When I remove the links, the page loads properly. Do you know what the best way to create links in this situation. Sorry for the poor formatting, can't figure out how to present it correctly.